# If GCM does not support upstream messaging for HTTP servers then how are upstream messages about user notifications supported for HTTP servers?

Tags: android, http, push-notification, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

The documentation for Google Cloud Messaging says that upstream messages from an Android device to the cloud are supported only for XMPP based app-servers and not for HTTP based servers. HTTP servers can be used only for downstream messaging.

However, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html) admits that the User Notification feature of GCM involves upstream messaging but is still supported for both HTTP and XMPP servers. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

While I've never tested it, I'm assuming user notifications's upstream feature is supported regardless of the server implementation,  since upstream messages related to user notifications go from one device to the GCM server to other devices of the same user. Since your server is not involved in this process,  it doesn't matter if it connects to GCM via HTTP or XMPP.

Comment: So can I also implement custom device to device messaging through GCM over HTTP - like two or more users chatting with each other real time?

Comment: @user87049 You can't do it with upstream gcm, since it can only send messages to other devices of the same user.

Comment: Eran, for User Notifications, GCM judges that it is delivering to the same user through a set of device registration ids for that user that our server provides to the Google GCM server while sending message for a user. 

If my Android app provide a registration id specifies the registration id of the other user, can GCM HTTP transfer a message from this device to the target device?

Comment: @user87049 The API for sending upstream messages from device to cloud accept either a sender ID (to send the message to your XMPP server) or notification_key (which is meant to send the message to other devices of the same user). I'm not sure what would happen if your app would try to send a message to a notification_key of a different user.